# Github actions how to do npm install only 1 time

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm using GitHub actions for deploy. And i need to build vuejs app, every time when pushing. Now all working coorectly, but every time i spend action minutes for npm install.

Can i install modules 1 time, and not reinstall it after every deploy?

```
on: push
name:  Deploy website on push
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [15.x]
    steps:

    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.2

    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

    - run: npm install --legacy-peer-deps     
    - run: npm run build    
    
    - name:  Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.0.0
      with:
        server: ${{ secrets.host}}
        username: ${{ secrets.user}}
        password: ${{ secrets.pass }}
        local-dir: dist/
        dangerous-clean-slate: true
```

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows

Comment: As the link shared by Evert above explains, you can use cache to speed up your workflows. Just be careful and don't store any sensitive information in the cache of public repositories.